# jQuery event not firing (advanced)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

For a dynamic added element via ajax or any after page load, I know that we have to use the `.on` like

```
$(document).on('click', '#dynamically-added-element', function() {
    // do something
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

I even wrapped mine with `(function($){})(jQuery);` to make sure no conflict; and to make sure everything should be run/loaded in proper order, I also have `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

Now that event was originally meant to run on `Page A` and it works well, but when I made and try it run on `Page B` having the same `id` for the main container and have the same child html, it doesn't work.

So I've done some experiment/tests and both works.

(1) So what I've done, I wrote exact same event listener through my browser's console with just `console.log` and click the target element, it works!

(2) On the same `.js` script, I've added exact same event listener with just `console.log` but wrapped it inside `setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);`, after 5 seconds, I clicked the target element and it worked!

So my question now is, why my original code doesn't work? Why these tests works? So what's the solution?

Also, my html elements aren't loaded dynamically, it's loaded on page load, generated via server side `PHP`.

**Edit:**
This info might be useful.

- running in magento
- js script is being included on `head` (that's why `$(document).ready` is really important).
- jquery script is being loaded before my custom script.
- Page A and Page B are on different pages.
- **It's not an ajax generated element nor js/jquery added element on the fly; it's generated on postback with `php` code**

(3) My third experiment works as well. But I don't want this to be my solution if possible, nor using javascript inline `onclick`. So what I did, I added a whole new script block inside the `php` file where that 'part' of the page is being included, with exact same code and it works. But the thing is, I have now two identical event listener.

So now I have 2 identical event listener (regardless if the other one doesn't work - only for Page B), 1 from within (internal) and 1 from external `.js` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#the-container a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: in first exmple u use jQuery sign and in second dollar $...check console for errors

Comment: `(function($){})(jQuery);` === `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @IvanKaraman on my first example, I'm using ```jQuery``` through my console because I know that ```$``` won't work. Also, no error.

Comment: Do you have a link where this is not working to share? It's hard to see what went wrong

Comment: Are pageA and pageB both being added dynamically via Javascript? (no new page load). Because some libraries set hide pageA instead of removing it right away, so the ID would still be in the page from pageA.

Comment: Page A and Page B said target element for click events are added on page load. @StevenBayer

Comment: Forgot to mention, both pages are on their own. @StevenBayer

Comment: Then yes, it sounds to me like pageA is probably still in the dom when JQuery is traversing for the element to add the event handler to.

Comment: Is the document.on inside the documet.ready ?!

Comment: @IdealBakija yes, it'd be something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2h4uLpov/)

Comment: Just leave the document.on indepenent and outside of the document.ready and everything should work fine

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I had a similar issue where I could only address dynamically added elements after a period of time had elapsed. The reason was that I was essentially creating them and then calling them at the same time. I was creating them via an Ajax() call, so simply moving my call statements into the "success" method solved my problems. Not sure if you have a similar situation, but I just thought I'd share.

Answer (score -1):

Just write you document.on outside of the document.ready that should work and comment your "e.preventDefault();". It worked on the fiddle when I changed it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '#the-container a', function(e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery event handlers are attached to the elements themselves not the selector, if you are instantiating an event handler to an element selector before the element has been loaded, it is not attaching a listener to anything.

For example this will not work:

```
$.get('http://example.api.com',
    function(data){
        $node = $('<p></p>')
        $node.text(data)
        $node.addClass('elementToListen')
        $('body').append($node)
    })

// this gets executed before the ajax request completes. So no event
// listener gets attached

$('.elementToListen').on('click',function(e){'do somthing'})
```

because the event listener has been set up before any of the elements have been added to the DOM.

While this will work:

```
$.get('http://example.api.com',
    function(data){
        $node = $('<p></p>')
        $node.text(data)
        $node.addClass('elementToListen')
        // here it is getting executed after the AJAX request in the
        // success callback
        $node.on('click',function(e){'do somthing'})
        $('body').append($node)
     })
```